# 96-pole VG female connector to 6x16 connectors

Tags: connector

I have a lack of knowledge of connectors and would be glad to hear any ideas of how to make my connections as simple as possible.

I have a female 96-pole VG connector and I want to divide this connector into 6 connectors (or 12) so I could plug it into my PCB (each connection for my 16 relays), which I am making right now.

For now I just have connection with a male 96-pole connector to a test board and extended with some regular wires. I really want to avoid using many chaotic wires and make it more advanced and easy to plug in and out.

[image: 96-pole VG connector]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying that you want to physically cut this connector into 6 or 12 separate pieces? Given that it has 3 rows of 32 pins each, there's no easy way to do that -- 32 doesn't divide by 6 or 12.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have 16 relays, you could certainly plug sixteen 2x3 male headers into this connector. Is that the sort of thing you're looking for? You really need to tell us a lot more about the purpose of the signals going through this connector.

Comment: I do not want to cut it. I imagined a 4x4 or 2x8 connector. The problem is that I do not know if these connectors exist. Male headers are something I am already using and it is a mess. This connector is for my test fixture where I measure voltages (from 10mV to 5V). All I want to know is if there are any other options, because a lot of plugging in and out is required and I found my current connections not suitable for that (maybe something I can purchase). I would love to explain more, but I really do not know what options are out there and for what of these options I need to explain more.

Comment: You're really not making a whole lot of sense here. You mentioned 16 relays, but now you say that the signals going through THIS connector are voltages that you're measuring. Which is it? Show us a block diagram of your system and which connections in it need to be easily disconnected.

Comment: Seems to me that you're looking for the *name* of a connector that would be suitable, right? If you search online for '2.54 connector' or '2.54 female', you'll find lots of ideas. 2.54 is the spacing between the pins in mm (=100mil). In Eagle they are in the 'pinhead' library. [Like this search I did at a reseller...](https://uk.farnell.com/w/c/connectors/board-to-board-connectors/prl/results?st=2.54%20female). This is for board-to-board. There are also board-to-wire connectors of the same type.

Comment: @MartinF: The connector that the OP shows IS a board-to-board connector, of the type commonly found in [VMEbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMEbus) and other [Eurocard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocard_(printed_circuit_board))-based systems. I didn't realize he was looking for other examples of the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can get "Dupont" style crimp connector housings and make up whatever kind of cable/harness you need. Male-male, male-female, a mix of the two, etc.

Here's a picture of that kind of housing in some of the housings available.
[https://www.amazon.com/QLOUNI-Housing-Connector-Adaptor-Assortment/dp/B0774NMT1S?ref_=fsclp_pl_dp_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0774NMT1S)

If you go to Pololu.com and search for Crimp housing you can see the wide variety available. They also have wires with termination already crimped on, you just need to plug the terminated wires into the housings, and then into your project.